# Calling JSON Array from an API that contains objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API that has it's data structured as such:

```
[
  {
    "bikeID": 5,
    "manuid": 168,
    "name": "Gran",
    "StoreID": 2
  }
]
```

Now I've tried using the appropriate URL to retrieve the data from the API:

```
public static class API_helper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeClient()
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.----------");
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", key);
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}

public static async Task<Bike> LoadData()
{
    string url = "http://api.----------/Bikes?take=100";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await API_helper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Bike bike  = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Bike>();
            return bike;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var bikeInfo = await DataProcessor.LoadData();

    BikeinfoBox.Text = $"Bike Nummer { wlrInfo.BikeID}";
    BikeinfoBox.Text = $"Naam is {wlrInfo.Name}";
    BikeinfoBox.Text = $"ShopID is { bikeInfo.StoreID}";
}
```

But proceed to get the error listing the following.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DHM_test_2.Bike' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

I've tried various other ways of making this a list through IList, List and ICollection but none seem to work. So how do I make sure that it returns an Array?

Comment: What about `var bikes = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Bike>>();`

Comment: Then, at the return statement it says this "Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DHM_test_2.Bike>' to 'DHM_test_2.Bike'"

Comment: Well it's a list, obviously you need to decide what you want from it. Do you want only the first item, or what if there are 0 or multiple items?

Comment: @Charlieface Well, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th items.

Comment: Then off you go and return them, you need to change the return type of your function to `Task<List<Bike>>`

Comment: @Charlieface It works but for some reason building returns Count = 1 instead of any of the data.

Comment: OK do you know how to use a `List`? It's like an array, use it like this `bikes[0]`, or use LINQ or similar to loop it. What you have done is tried `bikes.ToString()` and all that will show you is the count.

Comment: What it shows me when looked into is the type of the list. It does this before using bikes[0].

Comment: "What it shows me" what *what* shows you, how are you viewing it? In the debugger/watch window, in code, in the TextBox?

Comment: Quickwatch with a breakpoint on the return building;

Comment: OK, now drop down the + symbol and you will see the values. I'm afraid we can't spoon-feed you, you need to work out some of this yourself

Comment: I... told you the value. It's showing me DHM_test_2.Bike. Which is the type. I don't see any reason as to why that would be.

Answer (score 2):

The return type is an array, try to deserialize with Bike[]

```
Bike[] bikes = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Bike[]>();
```

Comment: Where exactly? Because this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Wait what? Maybe you need to use more words

Comment: Oh thx for editing my response, i had lost comment...